# How do i iterate functions in Python to create array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scala

In Scala–since it is a functional programming language–I can sequentially iterate a function from a starting value to create an array of [f(initial),  f( f(initial)), f( f( f(initial))), ...].
For example, if I want to predict the future temperature based on the current temperature, I can do something like this in Python:

```
import random as rnd    

def estimateTemp( previousTemp):
    # function to estimate the temperature, for simplicity assume it is as follows: 
    return( previousTemp * rnd.uniform(0.8, 1.2) + rnd.uniform(-1.0, 1.0))

Temperature = [0.0 for i in range(100)]

for i in range(1,100):
    Temperature[i] = estimateTemp( Temperature[i-1] )
```

The problem with the previous code is that it uses for loop, requires predefined array for the temperature, and in many languages you can replace the for loop with an iterator. For example, in Scala you can easily do the previous example by using the ***iterate*** method to create a list:

```
val Temperature = List.iterate(0.0,100)( n => 
      (n * (scala.util.Random.nextDouble()*0.4+0.8)) +
       (scala.util.Random.nextDouble()*2-1) 
)
```

Such an implementation is easy to follow and clearly written.

Python have implemented the ***itertools*** module to imitate some functional programming languages. Are there any methods in the itertools module which imitate the Scala ***iterate*** method?

Comment: Does your code works or not..?

Comment: @Arief yes it does, I want to find a functional alternative in Python to the for loop. Since Python implemented the itertools to immitate some functional programming languages, I suspected that my code might be clearer if I used one of the itertools methods. I hope the question is now clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalent program can be produced by using **`itertools.accumulate`**-:

```
from itertools import accumulate

accumulate(range(0, 100), lambda x, y => estimateTemp(x))
```

So here we have an accumulator `x` that is updated, the `y` parameter (which is the next element of the iterable) is ignored. We use it as a way to iterate 100 times.

Answer (score 2):

You could turn your function into an infinite generator and take an appropriate slice:

```
import random as rnd    
from itertools import islice

def estimateTemp(startTemp):
    while 1:
        yield startTemp
        startTemp = (startTemp * rnd.uniform(0.8, 1.2) + rnd.uniform(-1.0, 1.0))

temperature = list(islice(estimateTemp(0.0), 0, 100))
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, `itertools` does not have this functionality built-in. Haskell and Scala both have this function, and it bothered me too. An `itertools` wrapper called [Alakazam](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/alakazam/) that I am developing has some additional helper functions, including the aforementioned `iterate` function.

Runnable example using Alakazam:

```
import random as rnd
import alakazam as zz

def estimateTemp(previousTemp):
    return( previousTemp * rnd.uniform(0.8, 1.2) + rnd.uniform(-1.0, 1.0))

Temperature = zz.iterate(estimateTemp, 0.0).take(100).list()
print(Temperature)
```